# How to install PIL?

Tags: python

I have been trying to install PIL for quite a long time, tried almost everything

```
C:\Users\RUCHI SHUKLA>py
Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> sudo pip install pillow
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    sudo pip install pillow
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> sudo easy_install pillow
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    sudo easy_install pillow
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> sudo apt-get install python-PIL
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    sudo apt-get install python-PIL
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please help me to do it correctly, I have already wasted quite a long time :(

Comment: Do `pip install pillow` out of the python session.

Comment: It seems that you do not understand the *command line*, and are trying to do command-line tasks within the Python interpreter. This is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow; you need a general tutorial on using your computer (at the more advanced level that is often expected of programmers).

Comment: "C:\Users\RUCHI SHUKLA>" This part tells me that you are using Windows. This is the place where you should type the install commands directly, and *not* use `py` first. But because you are using Windows, `sudo` is not applicable.

Comment: Dude you're not even on Linux - `sudo` and `apt-get` don't work. Learn how to use your computer's terminal first. Not to mention that even if you *were* on Linux, running `pip` as `sudo` is an extermely bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like

```
C:\Users\RUCHI SHUKLA>pip install pillow
```

I can see you are using python3, use `pip3`

```
C:\Users\RUCHI SHUKLA>pip3 install pillow
```

For better management of python environment I suggest you to use [VirtualEnv](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

Also `sudo` does not work in Windows